# Ошибка PHP в контакте с Bootstrap и AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

PHP "не видит" bootstrap, выдавая ошибку

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected 'col' (T_STRING), expecting ','
>   or ';' in W:\domains\cabinets\details.php on line 15

Код и скрины приложил

```js
function getdetails() {
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var rno = $('#rno').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", 
    data: {
      fname: name,
      id: rno
    }
  }).done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    // вывод результата с details.php
    $("#msg").html(result);
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://mgimo.ru/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/x-icon">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_animation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simplefunction.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href=""><img src="//picsum.photos/50/50" alt="picsum.photos" title="placeholder picsum.photos" id="logo"></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="eos">
      <h2>Аудитории</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<body>
  <div class="schedule">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Номер аудитории:</h1>
        <input type="number" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onClick="getdetails()" />
        <div id="msg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db= mysql_select_db("schedule", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * from classes where cabid= ".$name."";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "</br>\n";
    echo "<div class=""col-md-3"">"."Номер аудитории: ".$row['cabid']."</br>\n"."</div>";
    echo "<div class=""col-md-3"">"."Кол-во столов: ".$row['stol']."</br>\n"."</div>";
    echo "<div class=""col-md-3"">"."Кол-во стульев: ".$row['stul']."</br>\n"."</div>";
    echo "<div class=""col-md-3"">"."Описание: ".$row['description']."</br>\n"."</div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ясно же написано: неожиданный 'col'. Пользуйтесь более продвинутым редактором с подсветкой синтаксиса, легко найдете ошибку. Код следует отредактировать и экранировать двойные кавычки или заменить на одинарные.
Плюс нежелательно код выводить напрямую, если так не задумано

```
echo '<div class="col-md-3">Описание: ' . htmlentities($row['description']) . '<br/></div>';

// Да и <br /> <br> используется, никак не </br>
```